# Asp.Net MVC5 survey-jquery - node_modules/survey-jquery/survey-jquery.d.ts' is not a module

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, survey

I'm trying to make update of survey-jquery library in asp.net mvc 5 project (.net framework 4.8), from version 1.0.78 to version 1.9.128. I've encountered after update problem with ,,is not a module" error.

Here is a code which was working before migration:

```
import * as Survey from "../../../../../../../../node_modules/survey-jquery/survey-jquery"
```

which looks the same as described in newest documentation of survey library.

I'm not sure if I should also do some extra action after migration ?

I've tried already:

1. different import types
2. cleaning all node_modules